# Как добавить посещение всех учеников одним разом?

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу на PHP сайт для учета данных, оплаты и посещаемости учеников.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как можно разом добавлять все посещения?** К примеру, вывести из бд всех, кто должен был прийти сегодня, далее поставить галочки на тех, кто посетил занятие. Но не понимаю, как это сделать. Все данные должны заноситься в отдельные ячейки, чтобы не сбивать подсчет оплаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для начала чуть изменить архитектуру БД:

   - таблица учеников (id ученика, ФИО - пускай называется StudentTable)
   - таблица учёта занятий (id ученика, дата занятия, флаг посещения - пускай называется UchetZanyatiy)
2. Заранее заполнить таблицу занятий, проставив напротив студентов флаг посещения, равный 0.
3. В php-скрипте, который Вы открываете первым (например, `index.php`), пишем что-то вроде:

   ```
   $conn = mysqli_connect($Server,$DB_User,$DB_Password,$DB_Name);

   // Получаем идентификаторы и ФИО студентов, которые должны прийти на сегодняшнее занятие
   $sql="SELECT
         `StudentTable`.`Student_ID`,
         `StudentTable`.`Student_FIO`
        FROM `StudentTable`
        JOIN `UchetZanyatiy`
        ON `StudentTable`.`Student_ID`=`UchetZanyatiy`.`Student_ID`
        WHERE `LessonDate`=CURDATE()";
   $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if ($res)
       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
           Students[$row['Student_ID']]=$row['Student_FIO'];
   ```

   В двумерном массиве Students у нас хранятся идентификаторы и ФИО студентов, которые должны прийти на сегодняшнее занятие.
4. Далее выводим на экран список учеников чекбоксами напротив каждого, для чего перебираем массив с идентификаторами учеников, например как-то так:

   ```
   <form method="post" action="write.php">
   <?php foreach ($Students as $id => $fio): ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="<?=$id?>"><?=$fio?><br>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <input type="submit" value="Записать">
   </form>
   ```

   Получается красивый список из фамилий с чекбоксами, и кнопкой внизу.

   По клику на кнопке во второй скрипт (который у нас называется `write.php`) в переменной $_POST будет передан массив данных, включающий в себя идентификаторы отмеченных учеников. Теперь разумнее всего будет весь этот массив отправить в БД:

   ```
   $sql="INSERT INTO `UchetZanyatiy` (`Student_ID`,`Prishel`) VALUES ";
   foreach ($_POST as $id=>$value)
       $sql.="('".$id."','1'),";
   $sql=substr($sql,0,-1);
   $sql.=" WHERE `LessonDate`=CURDATE()";
   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   ```

P.S.: возможны ошибки, прошу простить - писал на коленке.

Answer (score 1):

Берешь массив который получил на основании ответов и в цикле перебираешь его по условиям. Если ученик посетил занятие тогда  делаешь запрос к БД на проставления отметки. 
Если у тебя формируется массив в котором только данные о присутствующих учениках тогда можно построить запрос с конструкцией `IN`.